# How to make a function that should be 'polymorphic' with respect to two different objects

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I am creating a collision detection method between objects, however the objects can be different shapes, and therefore the collision detection method must act very differently when considering two circles rather than two rectangles, for example.  I am wondering if there would be a way to implement polymorphically this so that I could, with any two arbitrary objects call obj1.collision(obj2), and the correct code would be executed. Is there a way to implement polymorphism in a way similar to this?

Coming from Java, a not very elegant way to do this would be to use instanceof to determine the correct method to call, but I am not aware of this type of functionality in C++.

Comment: That's called [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch). A pure OOP pattern to implement it is via the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). [`std::variant::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) might be of interest

Comment: Perhaps one of [these questions](/search?q=%5Bdouble-dispatch%5D+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+is%3Aq) provides your answer?

Comment: https://gieseanw.wordpress.com/2018/12/29/stop-reimplementing-the-virtual-table-and-start-using-double-dispatch/

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is a C++ analogue of `istanceOf`. There are implementations of double dispatch/visitor that rely on it, with their own set of advantages and disadvantages (google "acyclic visitor").  Whatever you do isn't going to be elegant. It's just the nature of the beast.